# Why is "£" coming out as "Â£" when my HTML is rendered?

Tags: html, css, encoding

Code: http://pastebin.com/QBLeLyNq
I couldn't get the "code" thingy to work, thanks.

My error is here
Ran small business before. (£145 Profit, £6 Investment)

It is coming out as "Â£" on my site. I only know HTML and don't know too much about CSS or encoding. Could someone please explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `&pound;` for British Pound (and `&euro;` for Euro).

You need to [escape special characters](http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=latin) in HTML, unless...

You address the encoding issue on a document-wide level by adding the following line of code [*at the beginning*](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en#answer) of the `<head>` section:

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

Then you don't need to escape special characters individually.

---

Further reading:

- [Character encodings for beginners](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding)
- [Declaring character encodings in HTML](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en)
- [Declaring character encodings in CSS](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset)

Comment: This will work, though it's not accurate.  You dont _need_ to escape a pound, since it's not a reserved character.  The issue here is caused by encoding.  The file is clearly encoded as UTF-8 but served as something else (probably latin-1).  The entity avoids the issue; but it's not the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&pound;`

or specify the right encoding of your html file.
Add this in your `<head>`

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

and you can use any special character without having to look for the html version.
This is assuming that your code editor is set to UTF-8 (which certainly is).

Comment: The more detailed answer, good job. Exactly how people are supposed to do it.